# SQL 2008 Reporting Services Question - tablix visable

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I have a report that has two tablix on it.  I'm trying to control the visibility of the tablix using an expression.  When i hard code in a boolean value of 0 or 1 the visibilty works.  When i put in something like the following

```
=cbool(iif(First(Fields!bGeneralQuestionDisplayed.Value, "ClassificationNarrowed")=1 ,1,0))
```

it does not work.  I've profiler to verify that the query is running and returning the results.  I've also created a text field on the form rumming the same expression.. the result is a 1 or a 0.

anyone have any idea as to what might be causing the issue.
thanks
shannon

Answer (score 0):

According to [the FIRST documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159861.aspx), the second parameter represents a group.  Do you have a "ClassificationNarrowed" group defined?

Comment: I may be missing something.. but the First(Fields!bGeneralQuestionDisplayed.Value, "ClassificationNarrowed")... the ClassificationNarrowed is the second parm and that is the name of the dataset i'm looking at for it's results